# Broken hyperlink (URL) from vb.net email

Tags: vb.net, email, url

Our system is shooting an email having normal text and one hyperlink (URL with query string parameters like http://www.somedomain.com/xyz/abc.aspx?abc=1&xyz=384745&pfid=11441) to number of recipients.

Few of the recipients getting broken link like 
1. http://www.somedomain.com/xyz/abc.aspx?a

Just FYI, this URL don't have any space/ wild card/ newline/ SpecialChar etc. And not all the recipients reporting this problem. On top of that, surprisingly recipients of same email (To : xyz@xyz.com, CC : abc@abc.com; xyz@abc.com) is not reporting issue. Any of either member reporting this issue. Ideally if there is an issue then it should face by all recipients not only one.

My investigation points that problem is in Email client program at recipient side. Please help.

Comment: If the whole mail body length is long, sometimes this will be break after X characters. try to put line-breaks (\n) every hundreds chars in other place (not links)

Comment: As inon says: try inserting line-breaks. had this problem before because the html was all on line 1. And use \r\n for a linebreak, some programs (Windows!) like that better.

Comment: Inon & Willem @ line breaks are already there in the mail body.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks,

I got a work around of this problem. This problem was due to the different email programs exist like Outlook, Zimbra etc.

Workaround: We inserted the URL in the message body instead of mapping it on image button.

Thanks